# Automated push notifications from list, array or database based on user settings swift iOS

Tags: swift, database, push-notification, automation, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to coding and was wondering if anyone had experience with sending out a randomly picked push notification from a list, database, array or whatever with the user being able to control at which time they will receive it. I would preferably automate the process. Thanks for your time and help. I´m currently creating the app for IOS with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with **UserNotifications** in Swift, where the user could set a specific date and time, and then using that for the scheduled notification. I haven't done this before, but this is how I would imagine it's done.

Comment: Thanks for your input